# What is the time complexity of my nested loop? Should it be O(n) or O(n^2)

Tags: java, performance, big-o

Hey I used 2 free Big O checkers on the internet and both told me that my code was O(n^2) but I was certain that it had to be just O(n).

```
for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
        num = hwexamples[k];
        n = Integer.parseInt(num);
        int[] room = new int[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            room[j] = i;
            i = rndm.nextInt(365);
        }
        System.out.println(duplicatecheck(room));
    }
```

since the outer loop is restricted to 8 iterations, it cant be n^2 right? is there something i'm missing?

for more context, heres the method that i was calling:

```
public static boolean duplicatecheck (int[] room) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < room.length; i++) {
            map.put(room[i], i);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < room.length; i++) {
            int target = room[i];
            if (map.containsKey(target) && map.get(target) != i) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I was expecting to get O(n). What should I do to make the code more efficient?

Comment: Which Big-O checkers? The only one I've seen was just a dumb loop counter and not very useful at all. Also, `duplicatecheck` is a part of your analysis, so it should also be considered, not just the top block. Not that it will change the complexity, of course.

Comment: well, what is the result if you do not bound `k<8` but instead have it as the max size of hwexamples? if its still O(n^2), you would know that the checker probably just checks for nested loops and calls it a day

Comment: I'd agree that this is O(n)

Comment: It depends what variable you are classifying as `n`. The variable named `n` in your code is not the right one to choose, as that ignores whatever sequence the values of `hwexamples` are. The initialisation of `hwexamples` affects the order of the time complexity.

Comment: The Big-O complexity is *O(kn)*.

Comment: @user207421 and since k is constant, the asymptotic runtime complexity becomes O(n) – constants can be eliminated, O(1000×n) == O(n)

Comment: This is confusing. It looks like the first piece of code is running 8 test cases, and you are actually not asking for the complexity of *that* code, but of `duplicatecheck`. If I misunderstood, then what is  in your analysis? Also, where have you defined `i` in your first piece of code -- it is being *read* before being *written* to. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The first piece of code does not start out with a value for , so speaking of its time complexity in terms of  is not meaningful. This piece of code intends to create eight random inputs and call `duplicatecheck` with them.

It is incomplete, as it lacks a declaration of `i`, and reads its value before giving it one. It would make more sense if the inner loop had the statement:

```
room[j] = rndm.nextInt(365);
```

Also `hwexamples` is undefined.

It seems more reasonable to look at the time complexity of `duplicatecheck`, which indeed has a time complexity of O(), where  is the size of the `room` array.

If you really wanted to have the time complexity of the first piece of code, then realise that the input is not , but `hwexamples`. Assuming that array has 8 entries, the complexity is O(sum(*hwexamples*)).